# Connecting phone to PC internet using Connectify

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, connection-issues, wifi-hotspot, connectify

I am trying to connect my phone running ICS to my PC running Windows 7 to the internet using Connectify. Everything goes fine except when the phone tries to connect to my laptop wifi hotspot, it gets stuck at `obtaining IP address` . I tried to set the ip address to static in android but now it says connected but actually the phone is not connected to the internet.

As a `static IP and DNS1`, I set the address provided for the connectify network created in windows. I set the network length to 24 cuz without setting any value for network length, I wasn't able to save the setting in my phone.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Most of the other questions here tagged [tag:connectify] look to be similar. have you looked at any of them?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your support in Connectify. It sounds like your antivirus/firewall software may be blocking internet traffic. Check our [Firewall/Security Settings article](http://support.connectify.me/entries/20313068-Firewall-Security-Settings-) in our Knowledge Base.

If you are a PRO user and continue to have problems please submit a ticket by visiting our [website](http://support.connectify.me/home). We will work to help you resolve your issue!

Comment: You're from connectify? Awesome!